# VBA forumla longer than 255 characters Formula Array .replace with vba cell references

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take the following formula and have it so I can enter it into the cells in a new row in a listobject which gets cleared repeatedly. The formula is longer than 255 characters, so I need to break it up using the formula array .replace method.

=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX($H7:$H8,MATCH(X$5,$H7:$H8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($I7:$I8,MATCH(X$5,$I7:$I8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($J7:$J8,MATCH(X$5,$J7:$J8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($K7:$K8,MATCH(X$5,$K7:$K8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($L7:$L8,MATCH(X$5,$L7:$L8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($M7:$M8,MATCH(X$5,$M7:$M8,0)+1,1),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($N7:$N8,MATCH(X$5,$N7:$N8,0)+1,1),0))

The .replace will not replace the selection with my string. I do not understand why. Can someone please help me with this? Here is the code that I am using.

```
           tblabwk.ListRows.Add
        abwkrw = tblabwk.ListRows.Count
        tblabwk.ListRows(abwkrw).Range.ClearContents
        wslncl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Last Name").Range.Column
        wsfncl = tblconwk.ListColumns("First Name").Range.Column
        wsconcl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Contract").Range.Column
        wssuncl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Sun").Range.Column
        wsmoncl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Mon").Range.Column
        wstuecl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Tue").Range.Column
        wswedcl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Wed").Range.Column
        wsthucl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Thu").Range.Column
        wsfricl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Fri").Range.Column
        wssatcl = tblconwk.ListColumns("Sat").Range.Column
        abfrarw = tblconwk.ListRows(conwkrarw).Range.Row
        abfttlrw = tblconwk.ListRows(conwkttlrw).Range.Row
        strlstnf = "=INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wslncl), wswk.Cells(abfttlrw, wslncl)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH($U$4," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsconcl), wswk.Cells(abfttlrw, wsconcl)).Address(True, True) & "),0)"
        tblabwk.ListColumns("Last Name").DataBodyRange(abwkrw).Formula = strlstnf
        strfstnf = "=INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsfncl), wswk.Cells(abfttlrw, wsfncl)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH($U$4," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsconcl), wswk.Cells(abfttlrw, wsconcl)).Address(True, True) & "),0)"
        tblabwk.ListColumns("First Name").DataBodyRange(abwkrw).Formula = strfstnf
For i = 3 To tblabwk.ListColumns.Count
                        wshrrw = tblabwk.HeaderRowRange.Row
                        wshrcl = tblabwk.ListColumns(i).Range.Column
                        strabf = "=SUM((AAA)+(BBB)+(CCC)+(DDD)+(EEE)+(FFF)+(GGG))"
                        strsunf = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssuncl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssuncl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssuncl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssuncl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strmonf = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsmoncl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsmoncl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsmoncl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsmoncl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strtuef = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wstuecl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wstuecl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wstuecl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wstuecl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strwedf = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wswedcl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wswedcl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wswedcl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wswedcl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strthuf = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsthucl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsthucl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsthucl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsthucl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strfrif = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsfricl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsfricl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsfricl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wsfricl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        strsatf = "IFERROR(INDEX(" & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssatcl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssatcl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",MATCH(" & wswk.Cells(wshrrw, wshrcl).Address(True) & "," & wswk.Range(wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssatcl), wswk.Cells(abfrarw, wssatcl).Offset(1, 0)).Address(True, True) & ",0)+1,1),0"
                        With tblabwk.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange(abwkrw)
                            .FormulaArray = strabf
                            .Replace "AAA", strsunf, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "BBB", strmonf, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "CCC", strtuef, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "DDD", strwedf, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "EEE", strthuf, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "FFF", strfrif, lookat:=xlPart
                            .Replace "GGG", strsatf, lookat:=xlPart
                        End With
                    Next i
```

Comment: i think you shorten the formula using `SUMIF`. Replace `IFERROR(INDEX($H7:$H8,MATCH(X$5,$H7:$H8,0)+1,1),0)` with `SUMIF($H7:$H8,X$5,$H7:$H8)`. I guess this assumes that there will only be one match in the range, not 2.

Comment: I do not see any reason that is an array formula.  It can probably be entered fully using `.Formula`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman it would be `SUMIF($H7:$H8,X$5,$H8:$H9)`

Comment: and the whole can be shortened to `=SUMPRODUCT(--($H7:$N7=X$5),$H8:$N8)`

Comment: Or better:  `=SUMIF($H7:$N7,X$5,$H8:$N8)`

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone. I was able to figure out a solution after posting. I was missing the a set of parenthesizes. I was not familiar with sumif, does that basically combine the sum and index match functions?  Cell H7 will be a drop down list and cell H8 will be a value. I then want to go through and get the sum for each category from the drop down list. Like I said earlier, I managed to get it working by adding the parenthesizes and getting the formula formatting correct.